# Why doesn't the link generate where <span id="navigationLink"></span> indicates

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

I've been trying to obtain the outcome of this code for quite a while but it just doesn't seem to work. I want a link to be generated below but when I preview the script, the link doesn't seem to show up. I am genuinely clueless as to how or which parts of the script are wrong and would particularly appreciate anyone's help on this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function updateNavigationLink() {
            var link = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
                encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("start").value) +
                "&daddr=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("end").value);
            document.getElementById("navigationLink").textContent = link; 
        }
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ISHGUIDE</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <div class=naviselection>
        Start:
        <input type='text' list='start' />
        <datalist id="start" onchange="updateNavigationLink()">  
            <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
            <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
        </datalist> 
        End:
        <input type="text" list="end" />
        <datalist id="end" onchange="updateNavigationLink()">
            <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
            <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
        </datalist>
    </div>

    <div class=Finallink>
        <span id="navigationLink"></span>         
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: `<datalist>` does not represent an input control's state and so does not have an `onchange=""` event or attribute. Use the `change` or `input` events of the `<input />` element instead.

Comment: In other words, `document.getElementById("start").value` will get you nothing. You're selecting an entire datalist, not an option. Also there's no body tag, the link to css is not in the head and class `naviselection` needs quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straight forward way of doing it with minimal change to you code will be :

1. Give the onchange to your input
2. Give the start and end ids to your input

Just change your input bloks to this

```
<input type='text' list='startinput' id="start" onchange="updateNavigationLink()" />
    <datalist id="startinput" >  
        <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
        <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
    </datalist>   
<input type="text" id="end" list="endinput" onchange="updateNavigationLink()"/>
        <datalist id="endinput" >
            <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
            <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
        </datalist>
```

Also you might want to change this span

```
<span id="navigationLink"></span>
```

to an a tag with href

```
<a id="navigationLink"></span>
```

and when you set the value you'll do this

```
document.getElementById("navigationLink").href = link;
```

Comment: Thank you supra, I'm fourteen and have just started so I've been finding difficulties perfecting some parts of my code and ultimately making them function. Thank you.

Comment: Just keep practicing and you'll do just fine. :) ***Happy Coding***

Answer (score 1):

Change `onchange` event placement `datalist` to `input` then create `a` Element then add to span.

```js
function updateNavigationLink() {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("map link");
    element.appendChild(linkText);
    element.title = "map link";
    var link = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
    encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("start").value) +
    "&daddr=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("end").value);
    element.href = link;
      document.getElementById('navigationLink').appendChild(element);

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ISHGUIDE</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <div class=naviselection>
        Start:
        <input type='text'  list='startinput' id="start" onchange="updateNavigationLink()" />
        <datalist id="startinput" >  
            <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
            <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
        </datalist> 
        End:
        <input type="text" list="endinput" id="end" onchange="updateNavigationLink()"/>
        <datalist id="endinput" >
            <option value="The International School of The Hague, Wijndaelerduin 1, 2554 BX Den Haag">School</option>
            <option value="Centrum, Den Haag">City Center</option>      
        </datalist>
    </div>

    <div class=Finallink>
        <span id="navigationLink"></span>         
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you mark this answer correct if the answer is useful?

Comment: I have done so as it got me closer to my final product desired and was considerably helpful. However, saddr and daddr remain undefined when the map link is clicked and two map links are generated. Nonetheless, helpful code than has ensured I get closer to my final goal. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MohammadAliRony This is incorrect, it won't work
document.getElementById("start").value will always be undefined and when ever you make a change this will keep appending a new link

Comment: @supra28 Its quite an unwanted situation, would you know how to fix this issue.

Comment: @SkanderLejmi I've added an answer

Comment: @SkanderLejmiI have updated my coding it is working now.